# Loading a shared library failed with undefined symbol: __gcov_merge_add error

Tags: gcc, gcov, linker-flags

I am trying to integrate gcov for an existing build environment.
Adding -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage to CXXFlags got me through building and generating .gcno static files with out any issues. But once I start to deploy this package I am running into this below error failing to load a shared library

Error message undefined symbol: __gcov_merge_add

Can some one please help me with debugging why this symbol definition is missing.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: show the actual compile and link commands

Comment: Build_env uses dmake and it isn't pretty straight forward to present code used for build process. Thanks for the help.
Issue was some restriction on module size (.so size) that application can handle.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the linker flags `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` when linking your application/dynamic library.